# How can I get the Twitter follower screenNames of a given Username with Twitterizer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, twitter, twitterizer

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = "188817262xxxxx";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "GNqhB1gkxxxx";
tokens.ConsumerKey = "Q6xxxxx";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "2eZyxxxxxx";

var<TwitterUser> showUserResponse = TwitterUser.Show(tokens, "twitterUsername");
if (showUserResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
    {
    string screenName = showUserResponse.ResponseObject.ScreenName;
    Response.Write(screenName);
    Response.Write("<br>");
    Response.Write(showUserResponse.ResponseObject.NumberOfFollowers);
    }
```

With this code I can get my Twitter `screenName` and `numberOfFollowers`, but I want to print those follower `screenName`s on my asp.net application. How can I achieve that?

```
FollowersOptions options = new FollowersOptions();
options.ScreenName = "wallace740";
TwitterResponse<TwitterUserCollection> followers = TwitterFriendship.Followers(options);

// Response.Write(followers.Content);
```

How can I get the `screenName`s of my followers from this JSON (`followers.Content` gives me a JSON result)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate through the ReponseObject.

```
        foreach (var follower in followers.ResponseObject)
        {
            follower.ScreenName;
        }
```